# Sort array according to another array

Tags: javascript

I want do sort a array according another array

For Example:

```
let arrayParent = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
let arrayChild = [3, 1, 2];
```

**let myAnswer = [3, 1, 2, 6, 5, 4];**

In fact, I want the arrayChild at first and then etc.

Comment: What happens if an item from `arrayChild` is in `arrayParent` multiple times?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what's going on here? I don't see any sorting happening. Why not just `myAnswer = arrayChild.concat(arrayParent.slice(0, arrayChild.length))`?

Comment: @Luca I want sort parent for display to user.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map) and take the index of the wanted top values or move the other values to the bottom by using `Infinity` and their original index.

This works for more than one same value.

```js
var array = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    children = [3, 1, 2],
    result = array
        .map((v, index) => ({ index, top: (children.indexOf(v) + 1) || Infinity }))
        .sort((a, b) => a.top - b.top || a.index - b.index)
        .map(({ index }) => array[index]);
    
console.log(result);
```

A faster way, could be the use of a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

This works only for unique values.

```js
var array = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    children = [3, 1, 2],
    result = Array.from(new Set([...children, ...array]));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Arrays.sort()` and passing to it a custom comparator. Try the following:

```js
let arrayParent = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
let arrayChild = [3, 1, 2];

arrayParent.sort((a,b)=>{
  var indexA = arrayChild.indexOf(a);
  var indexB = arrayChild.indexOf(b);
  if(indexA == -1 && indexB == -1){
    return 0;
  } else if(indexA == -1 || indexB == -1){
    return indexA === -1 ? 1 : -1;
  } else{
    return indexA - indexB;
  }
});

console.log(arrayParent);
```